# Redmine: create issues into multiple projects from multiple email addresses

Tags: redmine

We are on Redmine 4.0.4 on Windows using Bitnami Redmine and try to implement incoming emails functionality.

Our goal is to create issues into different projects depending on the email sender.

Example :

- emails sent by `john@biometal.com` to `support@mycompany.com` should generate an issue in a project called biometal
- emails sent by `jane@tradmax.com` to `support@mycompany.com` should generate an issue in a project called tradmax
- ...

Considering the email sender matches users located in their respective projects, we are trying to run several commands (one per projects) like the following :

- `bundle exec rake -f C:\Bitnami\redmine-4.0.4-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host="myhost" port="993" ssl="1" username="myuser" password="mypassword" move_on_success="inbox/REDMINE/SUCCESS" project="biometal" tracker="Support" status="New"`
- `bundle exec rake -f C:\Bitnami\redmine-4.0.4-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host="myhost" port="993" ssl="1" username="myuser" password="mypassword" move_on_success="inbox/REDMINE/SUCCESS" project="tradmax" tracker="Support" status="New"`

Our problem is that when the first command is executed, all emails received are marked as read (even the emails coming from users that are not in the target project).

So when the next command in executed the email from the sender attached to the project is no more detected and no issue is created.

Does anyone have any idea how to make things work?

Thanks !
Fred

Answer (score 0):

Use your mail server's filtering function to sort messages into different folders based on the sender's address (e.g. from *@biometal.com → INBOX/Redmine/biometal), then make each Redmine import task look in its own folder instead of using the main INBOX.

Probably not the ideal method since it requires extra configuration on the mail server, but it should do the job no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you grawity for your suggestion, I finally found the trick, I had to modify the file imap.rb in order to force the emails to be marked as unread.

This is done simply by adding "imap.uid_store(uid, "-FLAGS", [:Seen])" at the end of the "imap.uid_search(['NOT', 'SEEN']).each" loop :[imap.rb file modifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNxDa.jpg)

Not sure this is the best solution but it fits our need.